# How to cover exception for before insert or update

Tags: unit-test, before-trigger

I have this handler class that handle Opportunity trigger for before insert and update .The test class cover well except for exception.It makes me wonder is exception can happen for before insert and update .

```
public static void  beforeUpdateInsert(boolean isUpdate,List<Opportunity> listOpp,Map<Id,Opportunity> oldMap ){
      try{

        //handle for new Opportunity
        if(!isUpdate &&  oldMap==null){
            for(Opportunity opp :listOpp ){
               if(opp.StageName=='Lost'){
                    opp.Description='Lost during log';
                }

            }
        }
        else if(oldMap!=null && isUpdate){
           for(Opportunity opp :listOpp ){
               Opportunity oldOpp = oldMap.get(opp.Id);

               if(oldOpp.StageName<>opp.StageName &&  opp.StageName=='Lost'  ){
                     if(oldOpp.StageName<>'Won' && !oldOpp.IsClosed ){
                          opp.Description=oldOpp.StageName;
                     }

                }

            }

        }
      }
      catch(Exception e){//Test class not cover here

         system.debug('Exception happen');
         //whatever logic will be here

      }
```

This is test class to cover the exception but it is not.I have no idea how to make it cover exception area above.

```
  static testMethod void testException(){
       Test.startTest();
       try{
       Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name='Exception');
       insert opp;

       }
       catch(Exception e){

       }
       try{
          List<Opportunity> lstOpp =[select Id,StageName from Opportunity Where Name ='Opp 1'];
          Opportunity opp1 = lstOpp[0];
          opp1.StageName ='Whatever';
          opp1.CloseDate=Date.Today()-3;
          update opp1;
       }
       catch(Exception e){

       }
       try{
          Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name='Exception',StageName='Whatever');
          update opp;//sure will throw exception because we not even key in the opp.
        }
       catch(Exception e){


       }
       Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Comment: First ask yourself, why you've used try catch? If you can't find any scenario then simply remove it.

Comment: I want to send email to alert support.The email features is already completed and I didn't post it here because it is not the issue. The issue is my test class is not cover the exception.

Comment: Looking at your abstract code, I don't think there is any need of a try catch.

Comment: Thank you.. if that the case , I will remove it. But if you like ,I would like you to Answer so I can accept.Saying that for those case there is no exception needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good practice to use `try catch` blocks but it's really **important** to understand its purpose. Remember you need to write code coverage as well.

So before using try catch block make sure that you've some scenario's were your code might throw some exception. If not then simply avoid using it.

In your code I don't think it code will throw any exception, as you've already 
**used proper `null` checks**

I found below line on the internet:

**Can the exception be thrown?** Does it make sense to catch a divide by zero exception if you already checked the divisor against zero and avoided dividing? Does it make sense to do something with a null pointer exception if you already know the variable cannot be null?